# Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to make a simple REST service in Spring Boot. Everything was working fine until I used CrudRepository. Now I am getting this error-

> ***APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field er in company.springBoot.io.Employee.EmployeeService required
>   a bean of type 'company.springBoot.io.Employee.EmployeeRepo' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'company.springBoot.io.Employee.EmployeeRepo' in your configuration.***

Here is my code-

**Controller-**

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {


@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@GetMapping("/employees")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
    return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
}

@PostMapping("/employees")
public String addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee e) {
    employeeService.addEmployee(e );
    return "Employee Records were added successfully";
}

@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
public String updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee e, @PathVariable int id) {
    return employeeService.updateEmployee(e, id);
    }

@DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
public @ResponseBody String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
    return employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);

}

}
```

**Service-**

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepo er;

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {


    List<Employee> list= new ArrayList<>();
    er.findAll()
    .forEach(list::add);
    return list;
        //return list;
}


public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    er.save(e);

}


public String updateEmployee(Employee e, int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
er.save(e);
    String s= "The Employee with id  has been replaced by Employee with id "+e.getId();
    return s;
}


public String deleteEmployee(int id) {
    //  Auto-generated method stub
    er.deleteById(id);
    return "Employee withh id "+id+" has been removed from the company";
}


public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
    return er.findById(id).get();
}


}
```

**Interface For CrudRepository**

```
package company.springBoot.io.Employee;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer>{

}
```

**Root**

```
package company.springBoot.io.EmployeeRest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= 
{"company.springBoot.io.Employee"})
public class EmployeeRestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmployeeRestApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

--------------------------------------***Update***--------------------------------------
I changed the folder structure like this-[image]

and Now I am getting this error-

[image]

Comment: This means springboot is not reading your repository class. This could be because your package structure isnt right. Simplese fix for this is to have your main class `EmployeeRestApplication ` at higher level than all other classes. like put `EmployeeRestApplication ` under company.springBoot.io.EmployeeRest and other classes under company.springBoot.io.EmployeeRest.controller, company.springBoot.io.EmployeeRest.service and company.springBoot.io.EmployeeRest.repos package .. With this you dont need `scanBasePackages` attribute for SpringBootApplication

Comment: Can you please post the POJO that you're using too, @Kshitiz Sharma ?

Comment: Place your `EmployeeRestApplication` in the `company.springBoot.io` package as recommended by the Spring Boot Team. If you put in somewhere else you loose a lot of the benefits of Spring Boot (like auto detection of JPA repositories etc. etc.). If you want to keep this you will need to add an `@EnableJpaRepositories` and specify the packages to scan. However the easiest is to just place our application in a top-level package.

Comment: @pvpkiran My folder structure is something like this- My Employee RestApplication lies in company.springBoot.Employee Rest Package and all other files lies in company.springBoot.Employee package

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried doing that but its giving more and more errors. My folder structure is mentioned in the above comment. Please have a look

Comment: Which basically means you are doing things in the wrong order.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, basically you are suggesting to put my application root also in company.springBoot.Employee package?

Comment: I'm stating, as I did before that your `EmployeeRestApplication` should be in `company.springBoot.io` as that is, judging from the little information posted here, what your top-level package is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177939/discussion-between-kshitiz-sharma-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the new folder structure and the errors I am getting. Please do have a look.

Comment: Basically your application is working.. Your `Employee` doesn't have an `@Id` annotated field. Also remove the `basePackages` from your `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Yeah. It is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your help @M.Deinum :)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing annnotation

```
package company.springBoot.io.Employee;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
@Repository /// here is the trick
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer>{

}
```

Spring didnt scan that interface because of missing annotation thus failed to create such dependency.

Comment: annotating the interface won't make a difference.